# pfSense IPv6 routing issues

Tags: routing, ipv6, pfsense

I'm struggeling to get my pfSense appliance to route the IPv6 traffic from LAN to WAN.
My public network is AA:BB:CC:/48 with the provider's router having AA:BB:CC::FF01:1001

Assigning the WAN interface address AA:BB:CC:0::1/64 and the LAN interface AA:BB:CC:1::1/64 gives "No route to host" when pinging from the LAN interface to an external address.
Pinging from the WAN interface works.

Also, the NDP table looks okay and I don't see any packets getting blocked by the firewall.
The RA service is enabled as a router only on both WAN en LAN interface.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more information from you side, how the interfaces are configured (ip/masks), what is current routing table and so on.

Pinging from WAN goes everywhere? Are you sure that you are using your assigned IP from /48, maybe you still use some P2P link and because of this is still working from WAN interface.

Thanks,

Comment: Hello @Drixter, IP/subnet length is as described. And yes, I can reach every external IPv6 address from the WAN interface (directly connected to the managed router). And no, there isn't any P2P link anywhere.

Comment: Can you paste: netstat -rn6 or other equiv for pfSense?

Comment: And did you tried from box from LAN? not pfSense itself?

Comment: pfSense is in use over IPv4 (v6 was added recently) so I only can ping from the configured LAN interface by specifying it (with -I) When specifying WAN it works, when specifying LAN it give's "No route to host"

Comment: netstat -rn6 shows me the correct prefixes for each interface and the configured default GW. So AA:BB:CC:0::/64 for WAN and AA:BB:CC:1::/64 for LAN

Comment: I strongly suggest to try from device from LAN, not from pfSense, i'm not sure that pfSense generally allow to use source address from one interface if traffic need to go outside from second interface, this could be blocked by default by logic of pfSense, it should use always outgoing interface as source, not forced to use different one.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if there is a service window to try this.

Comment: I hope after ISP fix this will work fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

The ISP wrote they've made a mistake in configuring the managed router.
So I'll have to wait 2 weeks to see if that's the cause of my problems.